# Modulation technique's effect on Active Sensor

Tags: wireless, sensor

Knowing that Bluetooth and ANT+ use FH-SS and ZigBee uses DS-SS, I would like to learn of the modulation technique's effects on a wireless point-to-point connection if I am implementing the wireless active sensor prototype (measurement sent from device to terminal, with the terminal sending back infrared LED intensity to the device to adjust the settings. It would be great to hear from you about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might get more feedback if you can rework your query into a single question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out the question here either, but I believe spread spectrum signaling is used to get around (narrow band) noise, increasing link reliability. It will, of course, create a broader spectrum of noise itself compared to sticking to a single channel. There should be a lot of decent material available on the subject and these specific methods.